# ORA-00904 when trying to perform conditional INSERT ALL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm total newbie to Oracle. Have the following problem. When trying to perform the following query:

```
    INSERT ALL
    WHEN (s.dwsact = 'I') THEN
        INTO TARGET1 (ID,VAL,DELETED_FLAG,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO)
        VALUES (s.ID, s.VAL, 'N', '11.09.17', to_date('59991231','YYYYMMDD'))
    WHEN (s.dwsact = 'U') THEN
        INTO STG.TMP_TABLE_FOR_UPDATE (PROWID)
        VALUES (t.ROWID)
    WHEN (s.dwsact = 'D') THEN
        INTO STG.TMP_TABLE_FOR_DELETE (PROWID)
        VALUES (t.ROWID)
    SELECT t.ROWID, s.ID, s.VAL FROM SOURCE1 s JOIN TARGET1 t  ON  s.ID = t.ID
```

I'm getting:

```
    ORA-00904 "T"."ROWID": invalid identifier
```

The tables look the following way:

Source1

```
        ID        VAL DWSACT
---------- ---------- ------
         8         10 I
         5          4 D
         5          3 U
```

Target1 is empty with ID,VAL,DELETED_FLAG,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO columns.
TMP_TABLE_FOR_UPDATE and TMP_TABLE_FOR_DELETE have only one column - PROWID.

Please, any ideas why? Already broke my head on this query.

Comment: The error tells you the issue. What is T.ROWID? Is it a Primary key?

Comment: @Isaiah3015 T.ROWID is ROWID (unique identifier of rows) in Target1 table, it is not a PK

Comment: Possibly look into your INSERT INTO TARGET1, you are missing the rowid column and went straight to ID .  INTO TARGET1 (ID,VAL,DELETED_FLAG,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO)
        VALUES (s.ID, s.VAL, 'N', '11.09.17', to_date('59991231','YYYYMMDD'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this (it worked for me)?  I did it empirically and observing that in Oracle docs they don't use table qualifiers for values.  Moreover, I changed ROWID using alias ROW_ID.

**I added s.DWSACT in SELECT, too.**

```
INSERT ALL
    WHEN (dwsact = 'I') THEN
        INTO TARGET1 (ID,VAL,DELETED_FLAG,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO)
        VALUES (ID, VAL, 'N', '11.09.17', to_date('59991231','YYYYMMDD'))
    WHEN (dwsact = 'U') THEN
        INTO STG.TMP_TABLE_FOR_UPDATE (PROWID)
        VALUES (ROW_ID)
    WHEN (dwsact = 'D') THEN
        INTO STG.TMP_TABLE_FOR_DELETE (PROWID)
        VALUES (ROW_ID)
    SELECT t.ROWID AS ROW_ID, s.ID, s.VAL, s.DWSACT FROM SOURCE1 s JOIN TARGET1 t  ON  s.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting "ORA-00904: "DWSACT": invalid identifier"

Comment: @mr.kalvados   see my updated version (you forgot the column in the select)